# How to get list of internal names in SharePoint with SSOM C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Is it possible, with SSOM C# code to get ALL internal names of SharePoint columns in a List?

Comment: Show us what have you tried..

Comment: I have tried the code guy's posted below but I figured I was targeting the wrong Site..

Thank you for comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
var siteUrl = "http://sp2013";
var listTitle = "customlist";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
        foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name:"+field.Title+" | InternalName:"+field.InternalName);
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that but I was targeting the wrong SP Site. It works!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is really straightforward. I am assuming that you know already how to get to the list (SPList), then you can use the InternalName property of each field of the Fields property.

```
foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
{
     Console.WriteLine(field.InternalName);
}
```

I haven't tested the code, to be honest, but it was part of an answer that I have just given to someone else using CSOM and the names are the same.

You haven not included any code in your question, so let me know if you need help with getting the list itself.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that but I was targeting the wrong SP Site.
It works!